# 1080P dual in car camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

In car cameras, now I know its been done before but the ones I found on Google are fairly old now, most are not 1080p or if they are its only a single camera setup.

What I'm looking to do is have a front mounted camera recording 1080p at a min of 30fps with an encoded bitrate of about 15Mbps to 20Mbps, on top of that I'm looking to have a second camera connected via USB or something similar recording 1080p at 30fps but at around 10Mbps.

So the overall loading on the storage hardware will be between 25 to 30Mbps (inc audio)

The question is, do we have any cameras that will do this, and secondly is the device powerful enough to encode 2 AV streams in to an MP4 or similar format at the same time?

Comment: Based on the originating site, I assume you want this for the Pi and not a standard dashcam, correct? I've added the raspberry pi tag on that assumption.